# DOMParser not defiend

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите почему их не видит редактор. И не подключается к разметке (собирается потом через вебпак).

Comment: а покажите вас `eslint`, он у вас есть в проекте? Кажется, там нужно прописать `target`: `browser`, что бы линтер понимал, какие есть глобальные переменные

Comment: Самый главный вопрос, чего это у Вас за проект? Это Node.JS или как? Или я ошибся?